# Is it true that if $f\sim h$, then $g(f(x))\sim g(h(x))$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f,g,h:\;\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$,
$\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)=0$.

It is known, that if $f$ is asymptotically equivalent to $h$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=1,
$$
then (if the conditions of the composition limit theorem are satisfied)
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(g(x))}{h(g(x))}=
\left|
y= g(x)\atop y\to 0
\right|=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{f(y)}{h(y)}=1,
$$
thus, $f(g(x))$ is asymptotically equivalent to $h(g(x))$.

My question is: is it true that if $f$ is asymptotically equivalent to $h$ and
the conditions of the composition limit theorem are satisfied, then
$g(f(x))\sim g(h(x))$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(f(x))}{g(h(x))}=1?
$$
I think the answer is "no", but I can't find any counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in the question and the description do not agree and I am using the latter.

Consider $f(x)=e^x-1$, $h(x)=x$. Let $g(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, and $g(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ if $x$ is irrational.

We can see that the conditions are satisfied. Notice that there are no rational points on the curve $y=e^x-1$ except $(0,0)$.

Now consider $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(f(x))}{g(h(x))}$. We shall see that the limit is $1$ for irrational $x$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for rational $x$, so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider $g(x):=x^\alpha\sin(x^\beta)$ for $x\neq 0$, suitable $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't proceed. We have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(f(x))^{\alpha} \sin^{\beta}(f(x))}{(h(x))^{\alpha} \sin^{\beta}(h(x))}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^{\beta}(f(x))}{\sin^{\beta}(h(x))}$. Why could it be $\ne1$?